# Uploading large excel files to Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, large-file-upload

how can i upload a large excel file and dataset (larger than 10 mb) to big query ?
Can anyone help ?

I tried to research a way to do it, but everything i found was a little bit complicated.
I just started working with SQL and I don't have much experience.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

!!! WARNING prior to answer.

The below answer will incur costs. You can use --dry-run to estimate the number of bytes that are processed for bq and then combine it with Pricing calculator:

https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/

What you are trying to achieve, is possible by loading a dataset from a google cloud storage bucket.

To make it easy for new users, there is a "Guide me" option from GCP on how to upload datasets larger than 10 mb.

[GCP "Guide me" site](https://console.cloud.google.com/welcome?project=double-venture-361417&tutorial=bigquery_import_data_from_cloud_storage&_ga=2.265835853.313245827.1671822961-1507608165.1671822961&pli=1)

Don't forget to first estimate the costs.

An example of how this can be used using a Google Storage URI is referenced in [this page:](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#bq)

```
  bq load \
    --source_format=CSV \
    mydataset.mytable \
    gs://mybucket/mydata.csv \
    ./myschema.json
```

Again, use pricing calculator to estimate costs.

To be able to create buckets on a specific project, you need specific IAM permissions, also referenced [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#bq)